# Access A UIImageView Outside Of Where It Was Declared

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, properties, uiviewcontroller

I have declared a `UIImageView` (`IBOutlet UIImageView *character;`) in a file called `GameViewController.h` and I am unsure how I can access this from another file `CharacterSelectViewController.h`.

All I need to do with it after I get it is to set the `image`. How can I access this `UIImageView` from another file?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the existing instance of `GameViewController` that is currently on display. How you do that from `CharacterSelectViewController` depends on how they are related to each other and you may want to set up a delegate relationship / navigate the view controller stack to find the correct instance.

Once you have the instance you just access the property:

```
gameViewController.character.image = ...;
```

In any case, a delegate type relationship is generally better than navigating the view controller hierarchy. This could be as simple direct relationship or a generalised relationship using an `@protocol`.

If `GameViewController` presented `CharacterSelectViewController` as a modal, then you could use

```
GameViewController *gameViewController = (GameViewController *)self.presentingViewController;
```

If `GameViewController` pushed `CharacterSelectViewController` into its navigation controller, then you could use:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
GameViewController *gameViewController = (GameViewController *) viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Wain. How can I set up a delegate? I have not done this yet.

Comment: For a delegate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c

Comment: But you might just want to set a direct reference (i.e. add a property to `CharacterSelectViewController` and set it). Again, it depends how the controllers are related...